# Swift: How to play video inside UITableView cell in loop(repeating again and again)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on an app in which i have to create a view similar to instagram reels. Most of the work is done only thing left is to play the video in loop within the cell.

I am using this code please suggest me how to play the video to run in continuous loop

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let Reelcell = self.tblInstaReels.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell_Reels") as! Cell_Reels
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 12.0, delay: 1, options: ([.curveLinear, .repeat]), animations: {() -> Void in
            Reelcell.marqueeLabel.center = CGPoint.init(x: 35 - Reelcell.marqueeLabel.bounds.size.width / 2, y: Reelcell.marqueeLabel.center.y)
        }, completion:  { _ in })
        //Reelcell.imgReels.image = UIImage.init(named: arrImgs[indexPath.row])
        //Reelcell.imgReels.isHidden = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            let videoStr = self.urlArray[indexPath.row]
            print( videoStr )
            
            let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoStr)
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
            
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.itemDidFinishPlaying(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
            
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            playerLayer.frame = Reelcell.Bkview.bounds
            
            Reelcell.Bkview.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            player.play()
            
        }
        return Reelcell
    }
    
    
    @objc func itemDidFinishPlaying(_ notification: Notification?)
    {
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `AVPlayerLooper` - [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper) ?

```
let asset = // AVAsset with its 'duration' property value loaded
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
 
// Create a new player looper with the queue player and template item
playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer, templateItem: playerItem)
 
// Begin looping playback
queuePlayer.play()
```

Comment: i already tried this but it is not working

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working" - is the video paused at the end? Is it not working at all? 
By all means, putting this kind of hard logic inside "cellForRow" is a bad practice itself, but let me try to understand your problem :)